# Controlling HTML5 video and short code approach

Tags: javascript, html, video, event-handling

I would like to use this approach to catch the “ended” event of the `<video>` element:

```
var v = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
v.onended = function(e) { /* handle event */ }
```

But it doesn’t get fired under Safari 5.0.4 (6533.20.27).

If I use `addEventListener`, it works, but there is more to code:

```
var v = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
v.addEventListener("ended", function(e) { /* handle event */ });
```

I saw the first example in W3C, but I’m wondering why it doesn’t work?

Maybe I’m doing something wrong?

Comment: It should work, as the `.onended` is the HTML5 event handler. Either Safari isn't supporting HTML5 properly, or your test code isn't working correctly. Could you post your test code?

Answer (score 0):

`addEventListener` is the correct way of listening to an event. The direct `onended` should theoretically work but if some other code elsewhere will also use this method to listen it will override your listening and you will not be notified.

So anyway: 
`onended` - single use, can be overridden easily without noticing it.
`addEventListener` - can support unlimited number of listeners